# Can't install gems with Ruby: “invalid byte sequence in UTF-8”

Tags: macos, encoding, ruby, utf-8, gem

I'm using Mountain Lion. I've installed Ruby first with RVM, then with **rbenv**. I can assure it's running the latest one with `which ruby`, it correctly points to the one installed with **rbenv**.

**gem** won't install any gem, it always throws me the same error (not always in the same file, but the same error with `split`:

```
Users/Macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1357:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/Macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1357:in `find_executable0'
    from /Users/Macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1564:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

I've tried setting these exports in my `.profile`, without luck:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I've also updated **bash** with brew, and activated it with **chsh**. iTerm2 is correctly configurated with UTF-8 encoding too.

I have no idea what else to do now.
I have XCode 4.6.3.

Comment: Did you try using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) instead of rvm? I 've also had some issues using rvm but none so far using rbenv

Comment: Yes, same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved cleaning up all files related with the setting up of the `PATH`environment variable (`.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`) and then installing `rvm`again.
Executing an `echo $PATH`revealed a strange character which broke bundler's processing of the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I have 64 bit Cygwin, Ruby 2.0.0 and gem 2.4.1 and was experiencing the same issue. `gem install ...`, `gem update`, everything ended with "*ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError) invalid byte sequence in UTF-8*".

I had also all locales set to "*en_US.UTF-8*".

I have read somewhere that it should help to set `LANG` to an empty string or "*C.BINARY*", but it didn't help. But it was good hint to start experimenting.

**Finally I have solved that by setting both `LANG` and `LC_ALL` to an empty string.** All other locale environment variables (`LC_CTYPE` etc.) was automatically set to "C.UTF-8" by that, `LANG` and `LC_ALL` remained empty.

Now `gem` is finally working.

I guess, that you had the same reason. When you have "cleaned" your dotfiles, your probably changed values of your locales.